# iOS: Get row position in a sectioned TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, position, segue

Is it able to acces selected row position in a sectioned table view within a `prepareForSegue` method?

This is my code for Segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CurrentEvent"]) {

    Tab1_DetailTableViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // get the selected index
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

}
}
```

I looked up several methods to acces the position directly, but i didn't find one. I think I have overseen something. Does anybody know a way?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand.. `selectedIndex` in your code is the row position of the selected row?

Answer (score 23):

To get the selected indexpath:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

To get the selected row

```
NSUInteger selectedRow = selectedIndexPath.row;
```

To get the selected section

```
NSUInteger selectedSection = selectedIndexPath.section;
```

To get the selected cell:

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedRowIndexPath];
```

Comment: Why none of this are working for me inside `prepareForSegue` ?

Comment: To get the row in swift, use `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row)`

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.2:

Get the tag of your cell into the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! taskCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row            
        return cell
    }
```

And then caputure it into the prepareForSegue trought sender:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! destinationControllerClass
        vc.passedIndex = sender?.tag
    }
}
```